# Cauchy random values in a interval [a, b]

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

How do I generate random numbers following a Cauchy distribution in a given interval [a, b]. I tried using explained here [Trucated distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution), but did not succeed

Comment: Yes. But I'm using the Monte Carlo method to calculate an integral over a given interval. And as I am using Sample Importance, my random number generator must generate values ​​in the range of integration

Comment: Not because I wanted to generate duplicate values ​​for two different distributions and did not put on the same topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the distribution of $\Theta$ is uniform on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ then the distribution of $\tan\Theta$ is Cauchy. Thus, if the distribution of $\Theta$ is uniform on $(\alpha,\beta)$ then the distribution of $\tan\Theta$ is Cauchy restricted to the interval $(\tan\alpha,\tan\beta)$.

To get a Cauchy distribution restricted to the interval $(a,b)$, consider $$X=\tan(\Theta),$$ where the distribution of $\Theta$ is uniform on $(\arctan a,\arctan b)$, for example $$\Theta=\arctan a+(\arctan b-\arctan a)\cdot U,$$ where the distribution of $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.